# Angular Calculate strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

i calculate the height with angular.js and add the value to the css style tag, its in a ng-repeat loop

with this line the calculation is wrong:

```
<div style="height: {{60.0 / 100.0 * (100 - (100.0 / 0.27 * (item.wert + 1.0 - 0.95)))}}%; ">
    <p>{{item.wert}}</p>
</div>
```

when i multiply item.wert with the factor 1 the result is right,
so this works:

```
<div style="height: {{60.0 / 100.0 * (100 - (100.0 / 0.27 * ((item.wert * 1.0) + 1.0 - 0.95)))}}%; ">
    <p>{{item.wert}}</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why i have to multiply it with 1?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `item.wert`?

Comment: its a float value, like 0.2, but its right converdet, when i use height: {{item.wert}}% - it works too

Comment: what is the type of  `item.wert`? If it string javascript does concat operation like `"1" + 1 === "11" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `item.wert` is a string instead of an int, so when you do `* 1` it actually turns it into an int and you can calculate with it.

Answer (score 0):

Type of `item.wert` depends on the value stored inside it. For example following code print `string`:

```
$scope.item={};
$scope.item.wert = "";
console.log(typeof($scope.item.wert)) //string;
```

But following code print number:

```
$scope.item={};
$scope.item.wert = 2;
console.log(typeof($scope.item.wert)) //number;
```

So result of your expression may vary depending on the value stored inside `item.wert`.

[Please have a look at the Arithmetic operators article of MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

**Addition (+):**

```
// Number + String -> concatenation
5 + "foo" // "5foo"
```

**Subtraction (-):**

```
 // Number - String -> NaN
    "foo" - 3 // NaN
```

**Multiplication (*)**

```
// Number * String -> NaN
"foo" * 2 // NaN
```

Hope above information answer your question.